# Pandas: Value Counts based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to generate a column `count` that counts the value of `pts` group by `id`. Condition is if `x` and `y` both contain `NaN` corresponding `pts` will be counted, otherwise it will be ignored.

Sample Df:

```
   id   pts     x     y
0   1   0.1   NaN   NaN
1   1   0.2   1.0   NaN
2   1   1.1   NaN   NaN
3   2   0.1   NaN   NaN
4   2   0.2   2.0   1.0
5   3   1.1   NaN   NaN
6   3   1.2   NaN   5.0
7   3   3.1   NaN   NaN
8   3   3.2   NaN   NaN
9   4   0.1   NaN   NaN
```

Expected df:

```
   id   pts     x     y count
0   1   0.1   NaN   NaN     2
1   1   0.2   1.0   NaN     2
2   1   1.1   NaN   NaN     2
3   2   0.1   NaN   NaN     1
4   2   0.2   2.0   1.0     1
5   3   1.1   NaN   NaN     3
6   3   1.2   NaN   5.0     3
7   3   3.1   NaN   NaN     3
8   3   3.2   NaN   NaN     3
9   4   0.1   NaN   NaN     1
```

I tried:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['id'])['pts'].value_counts()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test if missing values in both Dataframes by [`DataFrame.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html) and then count `True`s values by `sum` for new column in [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['count'] = df[['x','y']].isna().all(axis=1).groupby(df['id']).transform('sum')
print (df)
   id  pts    x    y  count
0   1  0.1  NaN  NaN      2
1   1  0.2  1.0  NaN      2
2   1  1.1  NaN  NaN      2
3   2  0.1  NaN  NaN      1
4   2  0.2  2.0  1.0      1
5   3  1.1  NaN  NaN      3
6   3  1.2  NaN  5.0      3
7   3  3.1  NaN  NaN      3
8   3  3.2  NaN  NaN      3
9   4  0.1  NaN  NaN      1
```

Or chain both masks by `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df['count'] = (df['x'].isna() & df['y'].isna()).groupby(df['id']).transform('sum')
print (df)
   id  pts    x    y  count
0   1  0.1  NaN  NaN      2
1   1  0.2  1.0  NaN      2
2   1  1.1  NaN  NaN      2
3   2  0.1  NaN  NaN      1
4   2  0.2  2.0  1.0      1
5   3  1.1  NaN  NaN      3
6   3  1.2  NaN  5.0      3
7   3  3.1  NaN  NaN      3
8   3  3.2  NaN  NaN      3
9   4  0.1  NaN  NaN      1
```

Comment: Please improve your answer. Code only does not help. Explain the code please. And simplify your code. One-liners also does not help anyone to understand whats happening there.

Comment: What is if `df[['x','y']].isna().all(axis=1)` is `False`?

Comment: @buhtz - then it counts like `0`